# Python - Center contents (not window) with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, center

When I search Google everything comes back for centering the window when using Tkinter. What I'd like to do is center the contents of the window.  I am thinking this might not be possible since you place everything at a specific x,y position.  So when the window opens let say it is 500x500 and I place buttons and labels and stuff.  When the user expands the window full screen or by dragging the corner can the contents recenter inside the window?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. You have complete control over what goes in a window, and you don't have to place things at specific x,y positions. Tkinter has three geometry managers - `pack`, `place` and `grid`, plus you can also use the text widget and canvas as containers for other widgets. Except for the text widget, all of the rest make it pretty easy to put something in the middle of something else.

Here's a couple of the most obvious examples:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Hello, expample1")
        self.label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

class Example2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Hello, example2")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    Example1(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    Example2(top).pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    root.geometry("300x300+100+100")
    top.geometry("300x300+450+100")

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But if you have lots of labels and buttons the relative position of them changes as you expand the window.  I added a few more items to the  windows and they do not stay in position, except the first one that is absolute center.  Wouldn't it be hard to place items all using relx/rely? Is it possible to have a frame centered that then contains all your widgets relative to the frame? If the frame is say 800x600 and you expand the window to 1024x768 the frame is centered and the contents of it keep their position inside the frame.

Comment: Look at this exmaple. How can the red frame remain centered on the screen and the button retain its position inside the red frame when the window is expanded?  Sorry I can't get the mini-Markdown to work.

Comment: `from Tkinter import *

def center_window(w=300, h=200):
    #  get screen width and height
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
    #  calculate position x, y
    x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
    y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

root = Tk()
#center_window(500, 500)

pane = Frame(root, width="300", height="200", bg="red", relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1).pack()
b = Button(pane, anchor="c", width=12, height=2)
b.place(in_=pane, x=10, y=10)
root.mainloop()`

Comment: @Husar: yes, it would be very hard to place all items using relative x/y positions. You really shouldn't do that. You're starting to ask for a very specific answer to a very broad question. You can do any sort of layout you want. Widgets can be in fixed positions, they can be centered, they can be relative to each other, and you can have any combination of the above. The best solution is to use `grid` or `pack`, and let tkinter handle everything when the window is resized.

Comment: @Husar: yes, it is possible to "have a frame centered that then contains all your widgets relative to the frame?".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to figure this one out. I am posting my answer in hopes it helps others.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()
f1 = tk.Frame(width=800, height=600, background="red")
f2 = tk.Frame(width=775, height=575, background="blue")

f1.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)
f2.place(in_=f1, anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)

#f2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
#f2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

l1 = tk.Label(f2, text="First")
l1.place(x=0, y=0)
l2 = tk.Label(f2, text="Second")
l2.place(x=100, y=300)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the grid manager and change the column weight. Changing the weight of a column will change how much it expands when the window expands, so you can do:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

contents = Frame(root)
contents.grid(row=1, column=1)

# Insert main contents into frame "contents"
```

This will result in a simple centring effect as the columns and rows either side of the main content are expanding equally to fill the window.